# How can I boot Windows from external hard drive using GRUB?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, grub

I have installed Windows 7 in my internal hard drive, and used a external hard drive box which turns the internal hard drive into a external hard drive.

I installed both Ubuntu and Windows 7 in my hard drive, and I installed grub. When I boot from the hard drive, it shows a grub menu with two choices: Windows (`sdb1`) and Ubuntu (`sdb5`).

I can boot from Ubuntu, but I can't boot from Windows 7 using that grub. However, I can boot from Windows 7 from `sda1` choosing `sdb1` windows.

How can I use grub to boot from `sdb1`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use os-prober then grub2-mkconfig:
you have to type these command as super user in ubuntu

```
os-prober
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

os-prober will scan attached hdds and  grub2-mkconfig will update grub2